# Gradle library conflict

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, module

I have a module dependency in my project. This dependency contains old version of google services. But my main project includes the latest one. As a result I get exception while building project:

```
Error:(93, 17) error: cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(<anonymous OnMapReadyCallback>)
```

It seems that Gradle tries to use older version of google services api. How can I exclude this library in a final project? I've heard about transitive dependencies. Is it correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can exclude a transitive dependency:

```
configurations {
  compile.exclude module: 'commons'
  all*.exclude group: 'org.gradle.test.excludes', module: 'reports'
}

dependencies {
  compile("org.gradle.test.excludes:api:1.0") {
      exclude module: 'shared'
  }
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

If you don't want to exclude the dependency you can also use a `resolutionStratgy` to force a version number across projects

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html